# Define for cases in if

Tags: python, if-statement, function

I want to define a function to use with `if` so something like this:

```
def containing(a, b):
    a == b.upper() or a == b.lower() or a == b.title() or a == b
c = input("Are you crying or smiling now? ")
if containing(c, "sMILING"):
    print("Great!")
elif containing(c, "cRYING"):
    print("Don't cry.")
```

Instead of this:

```
c = input("Are you crying or smiling now? ")
if c == "SMILING" or c == "smiling" or c == "Smiling" or c == "sMILING":
    print("Great!")
elif c == "CRYING" or c == "crying" or c == "Crying" or c == "cRYING":
    print("Don't cry.")
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: How you create your function (which is what it's called) is independent of how it's used -- a function meant to be used as `if myfunc():` is written no differently than one written to be used as `result = myfunc()`.

Comment: Do I correctly assume this is Python 3? (If it were Python 2, you'd want to use `raw_input()` rather than `input()` here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just make both arguments lowercase and compare:

```
def contains(txt, pattern):
    return pattern.lower() in txt.lower()
```